# USB, WIFI, Ethernet not working after kernel removal

Tags: 14.04, networking, kernel, ubuntu-drivers

I have removed previous kernels with purge after I was warned that my computer has ran out of memory. I have removed all except the one that my computer was using( which I found by typing uname -r in a terminal). After this, I received a warning that one of my video card drivers has been un-installed. After rebooting my computer, I couldn't use the internet, I couldn't plug any USB Flash Drive and I cannot upgrade my computer for it to run normally. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this issue. I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: You probably accidentally removed `linux-image-extra` package. You can download and install it back.

Comment: You are right but how could I get it in my computer? Is there a way to make the USB to work  at least?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the correct `linux-image-extra-...` package in Ubuntu repositories and download it. It should match your current kernel version.

If you can't use USB from that system, you can always boot from Ubuntu LiveUSB, where everything should work.

Copy the deb package to your HDD, then reboot into your system and install the package with `dpkg`.

An alternative way is to `chroot` from Live system, to your installed OS and install the package that way. But it is a bit longer to explain.